# Error trying to delete User Profile Service Application

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service

When trying to delete a user profile service application I'm getting an error. It goes ahead and deletes the proxy, but then I get the following error without completing the delete: "The timer job completed, but failed on one or more machines in the farm." How can I force the delete.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> ## Delete a User Profile Service application
>
> Perform the following procedure to delete a User Profile Service application.
>
> ### To delete a User Profile Service application
>
> 1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials:
>
>    - To use Central Administration to delete a User Profile Service application, you must be a member of the Farm Administrators group.
> 2. On the Central Administration Web site, in the **Application Management** section, click **Manage service applications**.
> 3. On the Manage Service Applications page, in the **Type** column, click the User Profile Service application that you want to delete to highlight the row.
> 4. In the **Operations** group of the ribbon, click **Delete**.
> 5. In the **Delete Service** Application dialog box, verify that you have selected the correct User Profile Service application to delete, select **Delete data associated with the Service Applications** to delete all data associated with the selected User Profile Service application, and then click **OK**.
>
> Reference: [Create, edit, or delete a User Profile service application (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721052(v=office.14).aspx#deleteapp)

If this doesn't work, turn your head at PowerShell and runt the following command. Beware, you get no warning before the application is deleted:

```
$spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "User Profile service application" 
Remove-SPServiceApplication $spapp -RemoveData
```

Reference: [Remove-SPServiceApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607874.aspx)

Comment: The first is what I've been doing I'll try the other. Thank you.

Comment: The command you gave me returned an error so I used this one: `Get-SPServiceApplication|Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "User Profile Service Application"}|Remove-SPServiceApplication -RemoveData` This ran, but then I got the same error: `Remove-SPServiceApplication : The timer job completed, but failed on one or mor
e machines in the farm.`

Comment: @LoneWolfPR Is your account member of the local Administrator Group of the servers your trying to change?

Comment: Yes. I've actually deleted and re-setup User Profile Service Applications in the past using this account. That's why I'm at a loss as to what is causing this now.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR Is there a synchronization going on, which hasn't stopped, and which may cause this problem. Msybe you need to kill and restart a service, to be able to delete the UPSA?

Comment: I've gone as far as stopping the admin and timer services, resetting the system cache and trying again. That didn't seem to help.

Comment: @LoneWolfPR It's when you say "Damn" and restart the entire farm to be able to delete the UPSA. But I guess that's not an option.

Comment: Do you have machines in the farm that are offline? Look on the Servers in farm page and check the overall health of your farm. Also check services on Server to be certain that you have stopped the User Profiles services on all machines correclty.